# Node - unexpected identifier

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, functional-programming

I'm trying to play around with Node and some ES6/functional stuff.
Here is two files.
**dog.js**

```
const dog = () => {
    return {
        test: (arg) => console.log("dog say: " + arg)
    }
}

export default dog;
```

**1.js**

```
import dog from './dog';

const d = dog()
d.test('111');
```

Node version - 10.4.0 (Node settings are fine)
When I'm running `node 1.js` - getting error **`Unexpected identifier`**, pointing on dog. What is wrong here?

**P.S.** 1.js was updated for proper usage of imported function, but even after that I'm still getting errors.

Comment: @RobC, still. Actually the problem is somewhere else I suppose, since error pointing on dog in import statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works, it logs:

> dog say: 111

However, ECMAScript Modules are [Experimental](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/esm.html) in node v10.4.0.

You'll need to run node with the `--experimental-modules` flag/option. For example

```
node --experimental-modules 1.js
```

Also see the note regarding .mjs extension for module file(s). So you'll probably need to change `1.js` to:

```js
// Note the .mjs extension
import dog from './dog.mjs';

const d = dog()
d.test('111');
```