# Unexpected Identifier {classname} when importing JavaScript Class into another Class

Tags: javascript, node.js, import

I'm using Node v10.11.0 and am running this script from Ubuntu 18.04.

My file setup looks like this:

**main.js**

```
import Login from './Login.mjs';

class Main {
    constructor() {
        const login = new Login();

        login.login();
    }
}

new Main();
```

**Login.mjs**

```
import readline from 'readline';

class Login {
    constructor() {
        this.username = '';
        this.password = '';
        this.readline = readline.createInterface({
            input: process.stdin,
            output: process.stdout
        });
    }

    login() {
        this.readline.question('What is your username?', answer => {
            this.username = answer;
        });

        this.readline.question('What is your password?', answer => {
            this.password = answer;
        });
    }
}

export default Login;
```

I'm calling the `main.js` with the following command:

```
node --experimental-modules main.js
```

This leads to the following error:

```
(node:7280) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.
/home/jrenk/Workspace/bitefight/main.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import Login from './Login.mjs';
                                                                 ^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at new Script (vm.js:79:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:251:10)
    at Proxy.runInThisContext (vm.js:303:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:657:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js 
    (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at createDynamicModule (internal/modules/esm/translators.js:56:15)
    at setExecutor 
    (internal/modules/esm/create_dynamic_module.js:50:23)
```

The `^^^^^` belongs under the `Login` but I can't seem to get it formatted right here in the question.

I also tried to save the `Login.mjs` as `Login.js` and calling the `main.js` without the `--experimental-modules` but this leads to the exact same error.

This question is similar to [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50792976/4011778) As I said above I already tried what is described there but no luck.

Comment: don't they all have to be `.mjs` - at least, the ones that use `The ESM module loader`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Native ES modules (`import` and `export` statements) can only be used in .mjs files in Node. In order to use them, entry point should be named `main.mjs`.

In order to use ES modules in .js files, ES modules should either be transpiled to fall back to `require`, or used natively with [custom ES module loader](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50847214/3731501). Since the latter isn't native Node.js behaviour, it cannot be recommended as a rule of thumb.