# Unexpected identifier {classname} when I try to import a class

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I get an "Unexpected identifier" error when I try to import a class.

I'm importing class this way:

**Class to be exported (WindowManager)**

```
export default class WindowManager {
    sayHello() {
        console.log('hello')
    }
}
```

**Class which imports (Main)**

```
import WindowManager from './handlers/WindowManager';

WindowManager = new WindowManager();
WindowManager.sayHello()
```

**Folder hierarchy**

Class which imports (Main) > handlers > Class to be imported (WindowManager)

**Extra info**

Throws the error at this line of code (Main)

> import WindowManager from './handlers/WindowManager.js';

I've looked into [Unexpected Identifier {classname} when importing JavaScript Class into another Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52677626/unexpected-identifier-classname-when-importing-javascript-class-into-another-c) and make changes and still nothing

Comment: Are you sure it’s being thrown by the import? Th line that looks. suspect to me is WindowManager = new WindowManager.” I don’t think you can instantiate an object from a class like that and it makes sense it would cause that error. It should be something like “WindoManager myManager = new WindowManager”.

Comment: @C.Peck Yep, I'm sure. I tried your syntax and its invalid... changed my declaration from `WindowManager = new WindowManager();` to `const windowManager = new WindowManager();` and I still get the same error

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by migrating to TypeScript.

**What is TypeScript?**

TypeScript is JavaScript on steroids, basically. It adds types, private methods, etc. Also provides a compiler which compiles your TypeScript code into JavaScript code! So you don't have to worry about compatibilty, you write on TypeScript and then compile to JavaScript with a simple command.

**How to install TypeScript?**

`npm install -g typescript`

**How to use TypeScript?**

- Enter your project folder (where package.json is);
- Generate tsconfig.json by running `tsc --init`;
- Create your TypeScript index file;
- Run `tsc` on terminal to compile ALL TypeScript project files to JavaScript;
- Notice that your index TypeScript file was compiled to JavaScript;
- Use the compiled JavaScript file as the main entry point on package.json;
- Start your app/website/whatever heheh.

**Notes:**

- Everytime you make changes to TypeScript file you have to use `tsc`
  to recompile the code and make the changes on the JavaScript file;
- VS Code comes with TypeScript support, if you're using Atom you can install TypeScript package by following this tutorial: [Installing atom-typescript package](https://atom.io/packages/atom-typescript).

**Happy coding!**

**Articles that helped me:**

- [VS Code Tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/typescript/typescript-compiling#_using-newer-typescript-versions)
- [TypeScript and Electron](https://medium.com/@davembush/typescript-and-electron-the-right-way-141c2e15e4e1)
- [How to auto-generate TypeScript config json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36916989/how-can-i-generate-tsconfig-json-file#36917406)
- [Why TypeScript? - YouTube video](https://youtu.be/4mRsiFoDO6k)